# How to create a variable with info that persists across runtimes

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am building a database and I want to be able to store a user input filepath and have it available as a variable even after the application is closed and restarted to prevent retyping the path with each launch.

Comment: Store it somewhere: file, database, cookie, etc.

Comment: You may want to look into `java.util.prefs.Preferences`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm not sure that you quite understood what I was looking for as that seems to be more for general application settings rather than a specific variable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a file where you store the information in the form :

```
key=value
```

For example :

```
filepath=C://myFolder
```

And use Properties to retrieve the information from the file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: Now the only thing that needs to be done is locating that file... If you store it in a jar, you'll have problems writing to it; if you store it outside, you'll probably face difficulties locating it...

Comment: Storing it outside should be the privileged solution in rich-client applications. Generally, the file is defined in a path relative to the directory where the application is copied/installed but it may also be the user directory.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance I actually forgot about the properties class to store info.

Comment: You are welcome. Properties should be unforgettable :)